# jquery @mention making the output a link

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, jquery-plugins

Hey guys i'm using this [plugin](http://jsfiddle.net/Hawkee/vq6MH/1/) from Hawkee. Its like twitter where you can @mention someone. I'm having trouble with the output. This method:

```
updateHidden: function() {
        var trigger = this.options.trigger;

        var contents = this.element.val();
        for(var key in this.id_map) {
            var regex = trigger+key;
            regex = regex.replace(/[!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)\+=-\[\]\\';,\.\/\{\}\|":<>\?~_]/g, '\\$&');
            regex = new RegExp(regex, "g");
            //contents = contents.replace(regex, trigger+'['+this.id_map[key]+']');
            //I changed the code above to:
            contents = contents.replace(regex, '@[' + this.id_map[key] +':' + key + ']');
        }
        $(this.options.hidden).val(contents);
    }
```

The code above will be outputted to a hidden tag affecting its **value** wherein

*Outputs:* **@[123:peterwateber]**  *//Format is @[].*

I'm using PHP as my back end.  My problem is **I wanna convert the output  to**

```
<a href="www.something.com/profile?pid=123">peterwateber</a>
```

I have a big problem with the codes here since I'm not good at RegEx. I have come up with the code:

```
    //THIS CODE SHOULD GET 1234,peterwateber,88,hi.

    $string = "@[1231:peterwateber] sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf@[88:hi]sddsf";
    preg_match_all("^\[(.*?)\]^",$string,$matches,PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    foreach ($matches[1] as $match) {
        echo $match.'<br/>'; //outputs 1231:peterwateber, 88:hi
    }

    preg_match_all("^\[([\w\d]+):(.*?)\]^",$string,$aw,PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    foreach ($aw[1] as $match) {
        echo $match.'<br/>'; //sad to say this code outputs the text '1231 and 88'
    }
```

Moreso, to be able to get the output I have this form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" data-post="request" method="post">
  <div class="control-group boxTextAreaHolder">
    <textarea placeholder="What are you thinking?" class="UITextarea" title="What are you thinking?" name="statuspost" id="statuspost" tag-status="this"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="tags" id="tag-post" />
  </div>
</form>
```

When submitted the output will be processed to this function. This function does not allow any htmlspecialchars and detects a url like `"http://stackoverflow.com"`

```
private static function validate_text($text = '') {
    // This method is used internally as a FILTER_CALLBACK
    if (mb_strlen($text, 'utf8') < 1)
        return false;
    // Encode all html special characters (<, >, ", & .. etc) and convert
    //$str = nl2br(htmlspecialchars($text));
    $str = htmlspecialchars($text);
    // the new line characters to <br> tags:
    // Remove the new line characters that are left
    $str = str_replace(array(chr(10), chr(13)), '', $str);
    $text = preg_replace('#(script|about|applet|activex|chrome):#is', "\\1:", $str);
    $ret = ' ' . $text;
    $ret = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])([\w]+?://[\w\#$%&~/.\-;:=,?@\[\]+]*)#is", "\\1<a href=\"\\2\" target=\"_blank\">\\2</a>", $ret);
    $ret = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])((www|ftp)\.[\w\#$%&~/.\-;:=,?@\[\]+]*)#is", "\\1<a href=\"http://\\2\" target=\"_blank\">\\2</a>", $ret);
    $ret = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])([a-z0-9&\-_.]+?)@([\w\-]+\.([\w\-\.]+\.)*[\w]+)#i", "\\1<a href=\"mailto:\\2@\\3\">\\2@\\3</a>", $ret);
    //$ret = preg_replace("#^*@([)([0-9-])(])#is", "\\1<a href=\"http://\\2\" target=\"_blank\">\\2</a>", $ret);
    $ret = substr($ret, 1);
    return $ret;
}
```

The problem now is that I don't know how to convert @[1234:peterwateber] to `**<a href="www.something.com/profile?pid=123">peterwateber</a>**` and how to exclude **anchor tags** from *htmlspecialchars*

Comment: Related: [Parse text for hashtags and replace with links using php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17245317/2943403)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Regular expression to take 1231 - peterwateber and 88 - hi is

```
preg_match_all("#@\[(\w+)\:(\w+)\]#', $str);
```

It depends on what kind of characters do you have in your input string. `\w` assumes you have only "word" characters (letters and digits).

```
$hidden_input = '@[123:web]hello world!';

preg_match('#@\[(\w+)\:(\w+)\]\s*(.*)$#', $hidden_input, $m);

echo '<a href="'.m[1].'">'.$m[2].'</a>'.$m[3];



function validate_text($text = '') {
    // This method is used internally as a FILTER_CALLBACK
    if (mb_strlen($text, 'utf8') < 1)
        return false;
    // Encode all html special characters (<, >, ", & .. etc) and convert
    //$str = nl2br(htmlspecialchars($text));
    $str = htmlspecialchars($text);
    // the new line characters to <br> tags:
    // Remove the new line characters that are left
    $str = str_replace(array(chr(10), chr(13)), '', $str);
    $text = preg_replace('#(script|about|applet|activex|chrome):#is', "\\1:", $str);
    $ret = ' ' . $text;
    $ret = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])([\w]+?://[\w\#$%&~/.\-;:=,?@\[\]+]*)#is", "\\1<a href=\"\\2\" target=\"_blank\">\\2</a>", $ret);
    $ret = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])((www|ftp)\.[\w\#$%&~/.\-;:=,?@\[\]+]*)#is", "\\1<a href=\"http://\\2\" target=\"_blank\">\\2</a>", $ret);
    $ret = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])([a-z0-9&\-_.]+?)@([\w\-]+\.([\w\-\.]+\.)*[\w]+)#i", "\\1<a href=\"mailto:\\2@\\3\">\\2@\\3</a>", $ret);
    //$ret = preg_replace("#^*@([)([0-9-])(])#is", "\\1<a href=\"http://\\2\" target=\"_blank\">\\2</a>", $ret);
    $ret = substr($ret, 1);
    return $ret;
}

var_dump(validate_text('@[123:peterwateber] fsdfsdfdsf'));
```

gives `string(30) "@[123:peterwateber] fsdfsdfdsf"`

Comment: thanks mate! but it gives me this output: 


Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 1 [4] => : [5] => p [6] => e [7] => t [8] => e [9] => r [10] => w [11] => a [12] => t [13] => e [14] => b [15] => e [16] => r [17] => s [18] => d [19] => f [20] => s [21] => d [22] => f [23] => s [24] => d [25] => f [26] => s [27] => d [28] => f [29] => s [30] => d [31] => f [32] => s [33] => d [34] => f [35] => 8 [36] => 8 [37] => : [38] => h [39] => i [40] => s [41] => d [42] => d [43] => s [44] => f ) )

Comment: didn't understood part about "exclude anchor tags from htmlspecialchars" - whatdoes it mean? Give us your input string and what do you wand to exclude

Comment: In this part, <input type="hidden" name="tags" id="tag-post" value="@[123:peterwateber] fsdfsdfdsf"/> this will be my process request, what I wanna do is get "123 and peterwateber" and changed it to <a href="123">peterwateber</a> the function "validate_text($text)" gets the value from the form(hidden tag) and outputs plain text.

Comment: thanks mate! I forgot to mention about the strings specifically the "fsdfsdfdsf" (those without @[ ]) I wanna use them too. If my hidden tag value would be: "@[123:web]hello world!" I want it as "<a href='123'>web</a>hello world!";

Comment: modified my answer due to your request.