# php comment with a an anchor <a> tag, http:// or url and the rest of the html tags are plain text

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, regex

I have this output: `<a href="#">sdfsdfsd</a>gdsfgsdfgsdgsdggsdfg`

Problem is that this function converts all html tags to plain text except those with url like  www.facebook.com **(converts it to `<a href="www.facebook.com">www.facebook.com</a>`)**:

```
function validate_text($text = '') {
    // This method is used internally as a FILTER_CALLBACK
    if (mb_strlen($text, 'utf8') < 1)
        return false;
    // Encode all html special characters (<, >, ", & .. etc) and convert
    //$str = nl2br(htmlspecialchars($text));
    $str = htmlspecialchars($text);
    // the new line characters to <br> tags:
    // Remove the new line characters that are left
    $str = str_replace(array(chr(10), chr(13)), '', $str);
    $text = preg_replace('#(script|about|applet|activex|chrome):#is', "\\1:", $str);
    $ret = ' ' . $text;
    $ret = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])([\w]+?://[\w\#$%&~/.\-;:=,?@\[\]+]*)#is", "\\1<a href=\"\\2\" target=\"_blank\">\\2</a>", $ret);
    $ret = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])((www|ftp)\.[\w\#$%&~/.\-;:=,?@\[\]+]*)#is", "\\1<a href=\"http://\\2\" target=\"_blank\">\\2</a>", $ret);
    $ret = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])([a-z0-9&\-_.]+?)@([\w\-]+\.([\w\-\.]+\.)*[\w]+)#i", "\\1<a href=\"mailto:\\2@\\3\">\\2@\\3</a>", $ret);
    //$ret = preg_replace("#^*@([)([0-9-])(])#is", "\\1<a href=\"http://\\2\" target=\"_blank\">\\2</a>", $ret);
    $ret = substr($ret, 1);
    return $ret;
}
```

I want something like from `<a href="#">something</a> <small>hello</small>` to `<a href="#">something</a>sadfsafasf &lt;small&gt; hello &lt;/small&gt;`

Comment: don't roll your own HTML validation, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not good at RegEx I just found the code.... how should I do it mate?

Comment: [for starters, don't use RegEx to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/497418).

Comment: @zzzzBov, Jeff Atwood does HTML validation with regex. (;

Comment: @Qtax, [he knows what he's doing](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html) and understands the risks.

Comment: I suppose to elaborate: An inexperienced programmer should be taught what to do and not to do. Oftentimes this leads to gross generalizations that an experienced programmer will understand. When you're little, you're liable to think that big things fall faster than small things. In elementary school you're taught that they fall at the same speed. When you get into physics, you then learn that big things *do* fall faster than small things, but that the difference is insignificant due to the size of the earth. It's this level of domain knowledge that's needed for validating html with regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`strip_tags()`](https://www.php.net/strip_tags) will strip all html tags from a string except tags you specify as allowed.

**EDIT:** as per your comment below;

To display a string that contains HTML tags as text without the browser parsing the tags you need to use [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) or [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php). Then to replace @mention with a link use a regular expression and [`preg_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

Here's an example of what (I think) you are after:-

```
<?php

$string = "Some text with some <span>HTML tags in it</span> and a @mention to someone";

// Turn special characters into html entities
$new_string = htmlspecialchars($string);

// Replace @mention with a link
$output = preg_replace("/@(\w+)/",'<a href="http://www.example.com/profiles/$1">$1</a>',$new_string);

// Will produce 'Some text with some &lt;span&gt;HTML tags in it&lt;/span&gt; and a <a href="http://www.example.com/profiles/mention">mention</a> to someone'
echo $output;

?>
```

Comment: Thanks mate! I tried it but my expectations are not what it seemed to be. I want something like twitter where you can @mention someone. the only problem I have would be posting it with an anchor tag in a text or string..

Comment: So you want to turn @mention into a link but strip out all other html? Let me know what it is exactly that you're trying to achieve and I might be able to point you in the right direction

Comment: here you go mate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042877/jquery-mention-making-the-output-a-link#comment12848031_10042877 

some parts are already answered. Thanks!

Comment: can't seemed to find a way to do this can you help me though? :(

Comment: @PeterWateber Can you please explain exactly what you want the function to do? What goes in, and what do you want to come out?

Comment: I want to parse HTML tags as plain text. but when i use "@mention" i want the output to be "<a href=#>peterwateber</a> some text here..." that excludes any other html tags. Like facebook is doing and also twitter....