# Parse text for hashtags and replace with links using php

Tags: php, regex, hyperlink, preg-replace, hashtag

I have some text with twitter-style #hashtags. How would I write a function to parse a body of text that might contain an unlimited number of #hashtags, take the text of the hashtag and replace them all with an `<a href="tag/[hashtag text]">[hashtag text]</a>`?

I've thought a lot about how to do this, but I am really bad at writing these sorts of functions with regex.

Example text:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus #tristique non elit eu iaculis. Vivamus eget ultricies nisi. Vivamus hendrerit at mauris condimentum scelerisque. Donec nibh mauris,
> pulvinar et #commodo a, porta et tellus. Duis eget ante gravida,
> convallis augue id, blandit lectus. Mauris euismod commodo mi ut
> fringilla. Sed felis magna, rhoncus vitae mattis varius, sagittis a
> eros. Donec eget porta ipsum. #Mauris sed mauris ante. Suspendisse
> potenti. Donec a #pretium #augue, eget hendrerit orci. Integer cursus
> scelerisque consequat.

Comment: show an example of text, and the result of that text after the parsing

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try using this:

```
$text = "Vivamus #tristique non elit eu iaculis.";
$text = preg_replace('/(?:^|\s)#(\w+)/', ' <a href="tag/$1">$1</a>', $text);
// $text now: Vivamus <a href="tag/tristique">tristique</a> non elit eu iaculis;
```

Here it is working: https://3v4l.org/WXqTr (click run).

Regex reference: [Space or beginning of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713310/how-to-specify-space-or-end-of-string-and-space-or-start-of-string), [Non capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-a-question-mark-followed-by-a-colon)

Original source: [Parsing Twitter with RegExp](http://saturnboy.com/2010/02/parsing-twitter-with-regexp/)

Comment: That requires a whitespace character to be before the hashtag, so `#hashtag blah blah blah` wouldn't be caught.

Comment: +1 - I forgot about the word character `\w`, that's better than `[^\s]`

Comment: This won't work with links that have hashtags in them. It'll break.

Comment: @MikeBarwick - the original question didn't mention that but it's a valid point, I've updated it to fix the issue.

Answer (score 4):

This will work with UTF-8 encoding texts and will show # (hash) before tags in content

```
preg_replace('/(\#)([^\s]+)/', ' <a href="tag/$2">#$2</a> ', $content);
```

Comment: I confirm that this works with Greek characters(UTF-8) where the above solutions work only with english chars! thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
preg_replace('/(\#)([^\s]+)/', '<a href="tag/$2">$2</a>', $your_content_here);
```

That will turn this: `This is a #hashtag`

into this: `This is a <a href="tag/hashtag">hashtag</a>`,

Assuming that you have `$your_content_here = 'This is a #hashtag';`

Comment: @Joe's regex is actually a bit better - mine would let you have a comma, period, or other symbol within the hashtag. Of course, depends on how you want to define "hashtag"

Answer (score 0):

It will extract and add links to every tag in the text whether it doesn't have any spaces between tags.

```
$text = "#test Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus #tristique non elit eu iaculis. Vivamus eget ultricies nisi. Vivamus hendrerit at mauris condimentum scelerisque. Donec nibh mauris, pulvinar et #commodo a, porta et tellus. Duis eget ante gravida, convallis augue id, blandits.Repost#high#fashion#photography#Ishan#portart#photo#Shoot#EishaChopra#luxe#twisty#creative#destination#style#Actor#model#beauty#gorgeous#makeup#and#hair#kamaldeep#fashionista#trending ";
$text = preg_replace('/#(\w+)/', ' <a href="tag/$1">$1</a>', $text);
echo $text;
```

Answer (score 0):

***The correct answer is this. For more reasons than one.*** But most importantly, you need to factor in if your string has URLs, all other answers will break otherwise. See example below:

```
$text = "#test Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus #tristique non elit eu iaculis. Vivamus eget ultricies nisi. Vivamus hendrerit at mauris condimentum scelerisque. Donec nibh mauris, pulvinar et #commodo a, porta et tellus. Duis eget ante gravida, convallis augue id, blandit lectus. Mauris euismod commodo mi ut fringilla. Sed felis magna, rhoncus vitae mattis varius, sagittis a eros. Donec eget porta ipsum. #Mauris sed mauris ante. Suspendisse potenti. Donec a #pretium #augue, eget hendrerit orci. Integer cursus scelerisque consequat. http://www.example.com/#wdwd/dwdqwdqwdqw#dwqdqwdq";

$text = preg_replace('/(^|[\n\s])#([^\s"\t\n\r<:]*)/is', '$1<a href="http://twitter.com/search?q=%23$2">#$2</a>', $text);

echo $text;
```

Comment: While this is the best answer here it still doesn't work 100% on the text I'm using it on. The problem is if my hashtag comes directly after a html tag, ie if the text is "<p>#whatever</p>", then it doesn't find it. I suppose it is because there is no space before the tag? How could I tweak the regex to match anyway?
(Sorry if it's a stupid questions, I've never got around really learning regex)

Comment: Please explain the purpose of adding the `i` and `s` pattern modifiers to your pattern.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the other answers amnd comments on the page, it seem rational to exclude some characters from the what constitutes a hashtag string.  Namely:

1. whitespaces
2. greater than symbol with is the start of an HTML tag and
3. classic English punctuation (if supporting other languages or scenarios, adjust for the necessary punctuation)

Not mentioned by other answers, I recommend the negated word boundary before the hash symbol.  This will enforce that the character before the hashtag expression is not a word character.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/0cXvu))

```
$text = <<<TEXT
Vivamus #tristique non elit eu iaculis.
Donec nibh mauris, pulvinar et #commodo a, porta et tellus. 
Donec eget porta ipsum.#Mauris sed mauris ante.
Donec a #pretium #augue, eget hendrerit orci.
Interference of#hashtag
Hash in <a>#taggytag</a>
"Living my #bestlife"
TEXT;

echo preg_replace('/\B#([^\s<,.?!"]+)/', '<a href="tag/$1">$1</a>', $text);
```

Output:

```
Vivamus <a href="tag/tristique">tristique</a> non elit eu iaculis.
Donec nibh mauris, pulvinar et <a href="tag/commodo">commodo</a> a, porta et tellus. 
Donec eget porta ipsum.<a href="tag/Mauris">Mauris</a> sed mauris ante.
Donec a <a href="tag/pretium">pretium</a> <a href="tag/augue">augue</a>, eget hendrerit orci.
Interference of#hashtag
Hash in <a><a href="tag/taggytag">taggytag</a></a>
"Living my <a href="tag/bestlife">bestlife</a>"
```

If multibyte support in the pattern is necessary, add the `u` pattern modifier. `/\B#([^\s<,.?!"]+)/u`

Answer (score -1):

I combined Joe's and jraede's solution.

UTF-8 safe and correct hashtag format (no comma etc):

```
preg_replace('~(\#)([^\s!,. /()"\'?]+)~', '<a href="tag/$2">#$2</a>', $text);
```