# Parse text for hashtags and replace with links using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

How to replace twitter style #hashtags with JavaScript?

I.e.
`this is a #hashtag` should become `this is a <a href="tag/hashtag">#hashtag</a>`.

For PHP: [Parse text for hashtags and replace with links using php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17245317/1245190)

Comment: 1. Write a regexp for the hashtag. 2. Call replace and replace the hashtag with whatever you want. 3. Figure out why you want an invalid href like `tag/hashtag]`.

Comment: Watch out for `'my #hashtag is cool, check out mysite.com/#bookmark'` which breaks in Kasper's answer

Comment: You should take a look at [twitter-text](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text). It contains code to parse internationalized hashtags, not just ASCII.

Comment: Why is this a duplicate? The other question has nothing to do with javascript so this one was much more useful to me.

Answer (score 3):

```
t = 'this is a #hashtag'
t.replace(/#(\w+)/g, '<a href="tag/$1">#$1</a>')
```

Gives

```
this is a <a href="tag/hashtag">#hashtag</a>
```