# Add text-color only to hashtags for tweets on HTML

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter

I have extracted tweets from Twitter using the Tweepy API in Python. I am writing it into csv and displaying it onto the HTML webpage. Is there any way to retain the blue color of the hashtags or add color specifically using HTML?

> ## cyber #infosec via @wired Intel Management Engine Flaws Leave Millions of PCs Exposed

In the above sample tweet that I pulled, how can I have #infosec in blue?

This is the jQuery function that I tried implementing but doesn't give the required output.

```
$('slider-container').overlay([
    {
        match: /\B#\w+/g,
        css: {
            'color': '#d8dfea'
        }
    }
]);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is it plain text that the API has returned? If you are going to display it on the browser, some html, css, and js will be needed.

Comment: @marlo : Yes the data is in plain text. I have added basic HTML/CSS for displaying the tweets individually. Which works fine. I wanted the hashtags to be in blue color. That is all.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17245365/3385827

Comment: You need to wrap a <span> (with color) tag around the matched hashtag

Comment: You are calling an `overlay()` method. Is it a function you wrote yourself, or a method of a library you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use regular expression.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("p").html(function(_, html) {
    return html.replace(/(\#\w+)/g, '<span class="blue">$1</span>');
  });
});
```

```css
.blue {
  color: blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>cyber #infosec via @wired Intel Management Engine Flaws Leave Millions of PCs Exposed</p>
```

Comment: Hi, when I run the above code snippet, it doesn't seem to change the color.

Comment: I have added css @Pooja, Try now.

Comment: Oops! My bad. I totally overlooked the CSS class selector. This worked perfect, thanks a lot @Krushnakant

Comment: This is great and works perfectly. I'm curious as to how this would work with anything after "www." to get links to turn blue. I can get it to work, but the blue class stops after .com. For instance www.test.com is blue until the second period.