# Parse Instagram usernames in text and replace them with links

Tags: php, regex

So based on some other posts here, I was able to parse hashtags from text strings using:

```
preg_replace('/(?:^|\s)#(\w+)/', ' <a href="https://instagram.com/tags/$1">$1</a>', $text);
```

Which turns every hashtag into a clickable link, and that's great!

However, for Instagram usernames (preceded by @), I use the following:

```
preg_replace('/(?:^|\s)@(\w+)/', ' <a href="https://instagram.com/$1">$1</a>', $text);
```

but here's the issue: usernames can contain a dot (.) as well.

So I changed it to:

```
preg_replace('/(?:^|\s)#([\w.]+)/', ' <a href="https://instagram.com/tags/$1">$1</a>', $text);
```

but the problem with this is that sentences that end with a @mention, will have the dot (.) which ends the sentence added to the username.

So what I need is a regular expression that includes words with dots, but not a dot at the end (dot that is either followed by a whitespace, or is the last character of a string).

E.g.:

```
Hi this is a @test to parse @insta.usernames using @regular.expressions.
```

Should return:

```
@test
@insta.usernames
@regular.expressions
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: A related topic: [Parse text for hashtags and replace with links using php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17245317/2943403)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a username can not end with a dot and there can be no consecutive or only dots, you can use :

```
(?:^|\s)[@#](\w+(?:\.\w+)*)
```

**Note** that in the pattern that you tried `(?:^|\s)@(\w+)` the group 1 value [does not](https://regex101.com/r/YWs5Ug/1) contain the `@`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iodNS0/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/0ekYe)

---

Another option could be (including the @ or #)

```
(?<!\S)[@#]\w+(?:\.\w+)*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ryXiFn/1) | [php demo](https://3v4l.org/4QiP0)

And in the replacement use the full match `$0`

Answer (score 1):

If you use a word boundary at the end I think that achieves what you want.

```
[@#][\w.]+\b
```

https://regex101.com/r/6Fpts4/1

That answers the `Should return` question.

For PHP replacement you'd need to capture the username bit:

```
echo preg_replace('/[@#]([\w.]+)\b/', '<a href="https://instagram.com/tags/$1">$1</a>', 'Hi this is a @test to parse @insta.usernames using @regular.expressions.');
```

https://3v4l.org/t3KYX